# R package glmnet installation error

Tags: linux, r, installation, cran, glmnet

First time post so my apologies for any posting taboos I violate.

I am following the installation instructions here: http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html with one small exception: I have obtained a tar ball and am installing from a local directory rather than a cran mirror. (I have attempted both)

I am working on a shared unix environment that I do not have sudo access to.

Using this command `install.packages("full/path_to_tar/glmnet_1.9-8.tar.gz", "full/path_to_local_libs/R_libs")` in R resulted in the following error:

```
 installing *source* package ‘glmnet’ ...
 This package requires a fortran 90 compiler. We assume
 that your fortran 90 environment is set up appropriately.
 Reference: Section on 'Using F95 code' in R-exts manual.

 R_HOME is /usr/pkgs/R/2.12.0/lib64/R
 R configured for gfortran...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -ffixed-form -fpic -g -O -c  glmnet5.f90 -o glmnet5.o
makeList item: gfortran: Command not found
```

I referred to the reference and found that updating my PATH to use `gcc.4.8.1` would alleviate this problem. I did so.

Retrying the same command resulted in the following:

```
installing *source* package ‘glmnet’ ...
This package requires a fortran 90 compiler. We assume
that your fortran 90 environment is set up appropriately.
Reference: Section on 'Using F95 code' in R-exts manual.
R_HOME is /usr/pkgs/R/2.12.0/lib64/R
R configured for gfortran...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gfortran: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath=/usr/pkgs/X11/R7.3-64/lib:[...]:/usr/pkgs/R/2.12.0/lib’
make: *** [glmnet.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’
```

I am aware that `-rpath` is a valid `gcc` option, but I am not sure exactly why the `-rpath` option is being passed to `gfortran`, or why it is failing as a result.

Any advice would be very helpful!

Comment: What happens when you attempt to download from a CRAN mirror?

Comment: using the link provided in the tutorial, the process hangs. using a different mirror;
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib
I am using http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html as the source for my local tar.

Comment: I just tried the code from the tutorial: `install.packages("glmnet", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` and it worked just fine... have you tried: `install.packages("glmnet")` to just let R decide which mirror to use?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Yes I have. The Results: install.packages("glmnet")
Installing package(s) into ‘/nfs/pdx/disks/asvs_vpcoe_7/usr/kennetho/Regression/sc
ripts/R_libs/’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
CRAN mirror

making a selection then produces:
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib

I'm less worried about the mirror issue(because I have a copy), and I am more worried more the installation, unless they are somehow related.

Comment: How are you using R? Command line? R GUI? RStudio?

Comment: Command Line.

I launch via typing "R" without quotes